# Arc Gis 10 dosnt show me spatial analyst in arcmap

Tags: geospatial, arcgis, geo, arcgis-server

I'm Using Arcgis 10 arcgis education edition & I'm working with spatial analyst & geoprocessing
spatial analyse is available in arc toolbox in arc catalog. but if I want to use it in arc map an error occur : Error 010096 there is no spatial analyst license currently available or enabled

How can I solve it?

Comment: This belongs on http://gis.stackexchange.com//

Answer (score 2):

Try going to the "Customize" menu, click "Extensions" and see if you can check the box for the extensions you are interested in, then try the tools again to see if they work.

Answer (score 0):

I make solution for this problem is :

costomize >> extention >> check